# the angular navbar generated with jhipster is not working properly

Tags: jhipster

When I generated my application with Jhipster 6.4.1, with bootswatch template, the navbar did not appear correctly. We cannot see the menu items like "Home", "Language", "Account"[image]

Comment: What bootswatch theme did you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem installing jhipster with angular and unity theme.
The color of the menu is the same color of the navbar. The menu only appears with overfly.
I've just modified the

> src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss

or

> src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css **if you don't use Sass option**

I just had on top of the file :

```
/*==============================================================
wrong Bootswatch color use correction
===============================================================*/

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

and voila !! my navbar menu appeard again !